# Homebrew remote repository on Artifactory

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, artifactory, package-managers

I'm trying to setup a remote repository for Homebrew on Artifactory. I'm following the steps as described in the following page https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-set-up-a-remote-homebrew-repository.

However, When testing the remote url connection (http://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles) I got this error:

```
     Connection failed: Error 403: Forbidden
```

I also checked the website in a browser and got the same error message. What are the work arounds for this?

Answer (score 2):

try this:
Create Generic remote repo named `homebrew` point it to `https://homebrew.bintray.com/`.

then set env `HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN=http://localhost:8080/artifactory/homebrew/`.

`brew install wget`

Comment: Docs on this - https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-setup-a-remote-homebrew-repository/

Comment: Did you actually get this to work?  The knowledge-base instructions don't work, we get an error.

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404                              

Warning: Bottle missing, falling back to the default domain...